# is it possible to change overlay iocn size when zoom osm droid map

Tags: overlay, android-maps, osmdroid

I spent many hours on it but not getting any fruitful response.I am trying to increasing the size of overlay icon when map is zoom but its not work, I am new on this please help on this

Comment: Increase how much? In the proportion of the zoom-in? Then you may need a GroundOverlay (https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_5).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, however you have to do the work. Basically, you need to create an MapView.onChangeListener and register it. When the zoom level changes, you need to iterate though your overlays and replace the icon with one of a different size.

At some point in your travels, you'll probably figure out that there will be concurrency/inconsistency issues with over zealous zoomers and panners. To handle this, you can wait until after the user stops scrolling or zooming after a period of time, then do the work.